# Kotlin class does not implement interface methods but abstract class does implement methods

Tags: kotlin, spring-data

I'm using `spring boot` version `2.1.9` with `spring-data`. I've defined a repository

```
interface TokenRepository : CrudRepository<Token, Long> {

    fun findBySubject(subject: String): Token?
}
```

For testing purposes I've created an abstract fake of a `CrudRepository` which implements all methods from the `CrudRepository`:

```
abstract class RepositoryFake<T> : CrudRepository<T, Long> {

    ...

    override fun existsById(id: Long): Boolean {
        ...
    }

    override fun deleteById(id: Long) {
        ...
    }

    override fun findById(id: Long): Optional<T> {
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

Now when I create an implementation of the `TokenRepository` which extends the `RepositoryFake`

```
class TokenRepositoryFake : RepositoryFake<Token>(), TokenRepository {

    override fun findBySubject(subject: String): Token? {
        ...
    }
}
```

the compiler complains that the `TokenRepositoryFake` is not abstract and it does not implement the methods `existsById`, `deleteById` and `findById` despite those methods being implemented in `RepositoryFake`. It does not complain about the other methods defined in `CrudRepository`. Why is the compiler complaining about missing methods and not about all the other methods?

An example of the error message:
`Class 'TokenRepositoryFake' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun deleteById(p0: Long): Unit defined in my.repositories.TokenRepository`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue. If I change the type of the `RepositoryFake` to

```
abstract class RepositoryFake<T, ID> : CrudRepository<T, ID>
```

and then change the `TokenRepositoryFake` to

```
class HDChainRepositoryFake : RepositoryFake<HDChain, Long>(), HDChainRepository
```

everything compiles. I'm assuming it has something to do with the way that kotlin handles generics, but don't exactly know why.